# VBA Copy rows of data where cell value of one column begins with numeric value (MMDD) to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, numeric

VBA beginner here. Trying to identify cells on Worksheet "All Data" in column H that begin with numeric value (1st 4 characters of a cell - represents MMDD)  and copy entire row to worksheet "MMDD". The cells Currently contain data like 0911MNND0 as well as 349MMMD1, etc. I am trying to copy only rows of data where the cell in that column begins with 4 numerical values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day Engel,

As i can't 'comment' just yet, i will post this as an answer.

Technically, you should edit or rephrase your question. As Stock Overflow is a place to ask questions and obtain answers, not code for specific cases.

However, I am more than willing to point you in the right direction.

I would suggest parsing the string of data in the cell through `left()` command, and then perhaps verifying that the new string of data is a number `IsNumeric()`.

Here is some more information about both functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function

You may need to convert your variable to an integer.

From there you can use the row property to obtain the row number, and then you can start to copy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row